# accessing the textfield values and giving the output to label in a table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a table view with two sections. In first section, there are textfields in all rows(let's say 3 rows) I have give given textfield a tag let's say 300. I just wanted to do the following calculation and present that output value in label in second section as soon as the user enters the values for those 3 textfields in section one. Again I have given a label tag 200 in section two.  How can I access the textfield in a particular row and do the following math. 
    [(Textfield value in row1 in section1)/0.052/textfield value in row2 in section1 +  textfield value in row3 in section1]  give the output to the label in section2.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to support anything before iOS 5, you can use storyboard and static cells. That way you can connect all the labels directly to IBOutlets straight in Xcode.

Comment: Well, I guess you could make the connections yourself in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. You can always find your controls in a cell by using viewWithTag: since they are UIView subviews.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
NSString *valueForRow1 = [((UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:300]) text];
```

To get the values from each of the UITextField in the tableview and then use the UITextField delegate methods to do the calculation.

```
– textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

In that delegate method you could check to see all text fields have a value and then perform the calculation